# Manipulating workbook data with two arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to get the information from one workbook, transform it to array (2D), add the first column (identifier) to an identifier array, match and paste it to excel. The code has some extra lines for basic organization.

The current problem is that, in the IsInArray function, I am getting a "subscript not defined", for the 'for position = LBound(arr) to UBound(arr)'.

Any idea of what might be happening?

```
Sub Pr()
Dim w As Workbook
Set w = ThisWorkbook
Dim w2 As Workbook
Dim end1 As Long, end2 As Long, i As Long, lRow As Long, lColumn As Long, t     As Long, k As Long, position As Long, g As Long
Dim WBArray() As Variant
Dim IS() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

end1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

'Optimize Macro Speed Start
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'opens the first workbook file
For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Cells(1, 2).Value

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Cells(i, 1).Value

    Set w2 = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select

    'text to columns
    Selection.TextToColumns destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7 _
        , 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17 _
        , 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27 _
        , 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1),   Array(32, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    end2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

'transform it to array
    WBArray = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(end2, 29)).Value

'loop to match information in two arrays

    For lRow = 2 To UBound(WBArray)
        If IsInArray((WBArray(lRow, 1)), IS) <> -1 Then
            t = IsInArray((WBArray(lRow, 1)), IS)

'start the information pasting procedure:
            w.Sheets("C").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 11)
            w.Sheets("M").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 12)
            w.Sheets("W t-1").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 13)
            w.Sheets("P").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 14)
            w.Sheets("A").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 15)
            w.Sheets("PC").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 16)
            w.Sheets("AM").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 17)
            w.Sheets("AM t-1").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 18)
            w.Sheets("P t-1").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 19)
            w.Sheets("F").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 20)
            w.Sheets("F t-1").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 21)
            w.Sheets("A t-1").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 22)
            w.Sheets("S").Cell(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 23)

        Else

'add it to the end of ISArray
            ReDim Preserve IS(1 To UBound(IS) + 1)
            IS(UBound(IS)) = WBArray(lRow, 1)
            k = UBound(IS)

            w.Sheets("C").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 11)
            w.Sheets("M").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 12)
            w.Sheets("W t-1").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 13)
            w.Sheets("P").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 14)
            w.Sheets("A").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 15)
            w.Sheets("PC").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 16)
            w.Sheets("AM").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 17)
            w.Sheets("AM t-1").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 18)
            w.Sheets("P t-1").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 19)
            w.Sheets("F").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 20)
            w.Sheets("F t-1").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 21)
            w.Sheets("A t-1").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 22)
            w.Sheets("S").Cell(k, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 23)

        End If

  Next lRow
'copy the file date from each source workbook to output workbook
'if the control sheet name (FILES) is changed, please change it in this loop

        For Each ws In w.Worksheets

            If ws.Name <> "FILES" Then

                ws.Cells(1, i + 3) = w2.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2)

            End If

        Next ws

Next i

'paste the is array to all worksheets

    g = UBound(IS)
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Range("A1:A" & g) = IS()

    Next ws

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'Close file and save
'w.Close True


End Sub



Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long
Dim position As Long
'default return value if value not found in array
IsInArray = -1

For position = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'subscript out of range
    If arr(position) = stringToBeFound Then
        IsInArray = position + 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Comment: 2 problems.  (1) `IS` is an illegal name.  Don't know how you got it in there without an error.  (2)  On the first pass, the array has not been initialized, so you have to test to see if the array is empty.  See Chip Pearson's page on [VBA Arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) for a useful function.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the answer. The IS is just an example, in my file the name is ISIdentifierArray (just cut it so it wouldn't be too long).
For checking if the array is empty, should that be done before I enter the loop that calls the function or inside that loop?

Comment: You can do it at either location.  To make the function more generally useful, I would do it within the function.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld So I put the isarrayempty function inside the isinarray function? Sorry, I am still trying to wrap my head around what I have to do.

Comment: I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you test the `LBOUND` of an unallocated array, you will get an error.  And that will be the case on the first pass through your `IsInArray` function.

Since links to outside websites are discouraged, I have copied the `IsArrayEmpty` function from Chip Pearson's web site page on [VBA Arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm)

Change your `IsInArray` function as follows (and add the `IsArrayEmpty` function as I show below:

---

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, Arr As Variant) As Long
Dim position As Long
'default return value if value not found in array

IsInArray = -1
If IsArrayEmpty(Arr) Then Exit Function


For position = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr) 'subscript out of range
    If Arr(position) = stringToBeFound Then
        IsInArray = position + 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function

Public Function IsArrayEmpty(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'From Chip Pearson [VBA Arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm)

' IsArrayEmpty
' This function tests whether the array is empty (unallocated). Returns TRUE or FALSE.
'
' The VBA IsArray function indicates whether a variable is an array, but it does not
' distinguish between allocated and unallocated arrays. It will return TRUE for both
' allocated and unallocated arrays. This function tests whether the array has actually
' been allocated.
'
' This function is really the reverse of IsArrayAllocated.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim LB As Long
Dim UB As Long

Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
If IsArray(Arr) = False Then
' we weren't passed an array, return True
    IsArrayEmpty = True
End If

' Attempt to get the UBound of the array. If the array is
' unallocated, an error will occur.
UB = UBound(Arr, 1)
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    IsArrayEmpty = True
Else
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 ' On rare occassion, under circumstances I
 ' cannot reliably replictate, Err.Number
 ' will be 0 for an unallocated, empty array.
 ' On these occassions, LBound is 0 and
 ' UBoung is -1.
 ' To accomodate the weird behavior, test to
 ' see if LB > UB. If so, the array is not
 ' allocated.
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 Err.Clear
 LB = LBound(Arr)
 If LB > UB Then
 IsArrayEmpty = True
 Else
 IsArrayEmpty = False
 End If
End If

End Function
```

---

Comment: Much Appreciated. Only one question:
On the "If IsArrayEmpy(arr) then exit function", on the first iteration the array will be empty, so if it stops the function I cannot get the position to continue the macro and paste the information? If that happens, wouldn't the next iteration would also find return and empty array (and so on)?

Comment: @DGMS89 Huh? Array is empty means you have not even declared any dimensions. Once you declare a dimension, the array will no longer be empty.  But you don't do that within the IsInArray function as it now exists. Once you set a dimension, the array will no longer be empty.  If that is what you want, you could add code to ReDim the array if it is empty, to whatever you want the initial dimensions set.

Comment: @RonRosefeld Yes, now I understand, I though it would break out of the function with no position value, but that does not happen. 
One more thing, if you don't mind: in the second part of the loop in the main sub, the redim preserve is also giving a subscription error. Can that be for the same reason? (the array being empty)

Comment: @DGMS89 Yes.  If `IS` has no dimensions, then `Ubound(IS)` will return an error.

Comment: @RonRosefeld OK. Since this array is dynamic (I don't know how large it is going to be), should I just declare it initially `IS(0 to 1)` and then ReDim? Or is there another way?

Comment: @DGMS89 If you are going to change it, you `Dim IS() : ReDim IS(0)` and then you can do your `ReDim Preserve`.  In those situations, though, I usually use a `Collection` or `Dictionary` object to collect the individual bits of data.

Answer (score -1):

In your function IsInArray, can you try this :

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long
Dim position As Long
Dim returnValue as Long
'default return value if value not found in array
returnValue  = -1

For position = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'subscript out of range
    If arr(position) = stringToBeFound Then
        returnValue  = position + 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

IsInArray = returnValue

End Function`
```

I think when you write : IsInArray = -1, you're ending your function.

Comment: `IsInArray = -1` definitely does **NOT** end the function

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try and see how it works.